# Polars Rolling Count With Temporal Window

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I'm trying to write a method for a features pipeline that returns a polars expression. The method should take a column name as a string and an integer number of days. I want to perform a rolling count on that column using a window equal to the number of days.

There doesn't seem to be a `rolling_count` expression, so I attempted to use `rolling_sum` to no avail.

```
def temporal_rolling_count(col: str, days: int) -> pl.Expr:
    return (
        pl.lit(1)
        .rolling_sum(window_size=f"{days}d", by="date_time")
        .over(col)
        .fill_null(0)
    )
```

I also tried this method, which was closer but still didn't work in all cases

```
def temporal_rolling_count(col: str, days: int) -> pl.Expr:
    return (
        pl.col(col)
        .cumcount()
        .over(col, (pl.col("date_time") - pl.col("date_time").min()).dt.days() % days == 0)
        .fill_null(0)
    )
```

Is there anyway to achieve this by returning an expression? Or will I have to act on the DataFrame directly, maybe by using `groupby_rolling`?

Comment: Would `pl.col(col).clip(1, 1)` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the suggestion from @jqurious, by using `.clip` I was able to achieve the desired outcome without acting on the DataFrame.

```
def temporal_rolling_count(col: str, days: int) -> pl.Expr:
    return (
        pl.col(col).clip(1,1)
        .rolling_sum(window_size=f"{days}d", by="date_time")
        .over(col)
        .fill_null(0)
    )
```

**EDIT**

I managed to perform the same thing but only count when a condition was true by doing the following.

```
def temporal_rolling_count(col: str, days: int) -> pl.Expr:
    return (
        pl.when(condition).then(1).otherwise(0)
        .rolling_sum(window_size=f"{days}d", by="date_time")
        .over(col)
        .fill_null(0)
    )
```

Comment: Ah, when/then is a cleaner solution, nice find.

Comment: what did you use for your condition?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do it with the rolling_sum if you create a dummy variable, which one can delete later.

Example:

```
# Initial dataframe
shape: (7, 2)
┌───────┬─────────────────────┐
│ group ┆ date_time           │
│ ---   ┆ ---                 │
│ str   ┆ datetime[μs]        │
╞═══════╪═════════════════════╡
│ a     ┆ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 │
│ a     ┆ 2023-01-02 00:00:00 │
│ a     ┆ 2023-01-02 00:00:00 │
│ b     ┆ 2023-01-02 00:00:00 │
│ b     ┆ 2023-01-05 00:00:00 │
│ b     ┆ 2023-01-05 00:00:00 │
│ b     ┆ 2023-01-07 00:00:00 │
└───────┴─────────────────────┘

(
    df.with_columns(ones = pl.lit(1))
    .with_columns(
        rolling_count = pl.col('ones')
            .rolling_sum(window_size='2d', by='date_time', closed='both')
            .over('group'))
    .drop('ones')
)

# Result
shape: (7, 3)
┌───────┬─────────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ group ┆ date_time           ┆ rolling_count │
│ ---   ┆ ---                 ┆ ---           │
│ str   ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i32           │
╞═══════╪═════════════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ a     ┆ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1             │
│ a     ┆ 2023-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 2             │
│ a     ┆ 2023-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 3             │
│ b     ┆ 2023-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 1             │
│ b     ┆ 2023-01-05 00:00:00 ┆ 1             │
│ b     ┆ 2023-01-05 00:00:00 ┆ 2             │
│ b     ┆ 2023-01-07 00:00:00 ┆ 3             │
└───────┴─────────────────────┴───────────────┘
```